# How to fetch database values in html text boxes on button press without refreshing page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to fetch database values into text boxes without refreshing page. with page refresh it goes fine but I don't want to refresh it.

My code is shown below.

**PHP**

```html
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from `registration`");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo "<tr>
 <td>".$row['Emp_Code']."</td>
 <td>".$row['Full_Name']."</td>
 <td>".$row['Permanent_Address']."</td>
 <td>".$row['Mobile_No']."</td>
 <tr>";
 if (isset($_POST['Fetchdetails']))
   {
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $fetchquery = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from `registration` where `Emp_Code` = '$userid'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
    {
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchquery))
     {
      $employeecode=$row['Emp_Code'];
      $fullname=$row['Full_Name'];
      $permanentaddress=$row['Permanent_Address'];
      $mobileno=$row['Mobile_No'];
     }
    }
   }
}
?>
```

My HTML Code is

```html
<html>
<body>
<div align="center" id="div">
   <table width="400" border="1">
       <tr align="right" style="background-color:#FFF;">
           <td width="100">Permanent Address :&nbsp;</td>
           <td width="100">&nbsp;
              <input type="text" name="permanentaddress" id="permanentaddress" placeholder="Permanent Address" size="15" value="<?php echo $permanentaddress;?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       <tr align="right" style="background-color:#FFF;">
           <td width="100">Employee Code :&nbsp;</td>
           <td width="100">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="employeecode" id="employeecode" placeholder="Employee Code" size="15" value="<?php echo $employeecode;?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       <tr align="right" style="background-color:#FFF;">
           <td width="100">Full Name :&nbsp;</td>
           <td width="100">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" size="15" value="<?php echo $fullname;?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr align="right" style="background-color:#FFF;">
           <td width="100">Mobile No. :&nbsp;</td>
           <td width="100">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" placeholder="Mobile No." size="15" value="<?php echo $mobileno;?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
      <br>
  <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Fetchdetails" value="Fetch Details" id="Fetchdetails" />
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How can I fetch values from database into text boxes without refreshing web page?

Comment: Check out ajax requests.

Comment: why are you doing isset($_POST['Fetchdetails']) in you database query ?

Comment: @mighTY: I am facing problem in using ajax, please tell how to do that.

Comment: @t-n-y : isset($_POST['Fetchdetails']) is using to fetch values from database into text boxes.

Comment: @Arpit_K what's the problem you've got with ajax? Post your ajax code and we can help you with it. If you don't know anything at all about ajax yet, then please take a tutorial online (there are hundreds of free ones) and come back with a question when you have written some code of your own.

Comment: @ADyson: This is my ajax code...    



$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Fetchdetails').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HR_Panel.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
     
        }
    });
});
});



I am not getting what to write in success function and this neither works.

Comment: i know, but it is weird. POST should be use to put data in database, not to fetch them. i think that you have a little construction problem here.
The only way to fix that without changing everything is to use ajax but i would recommand to change the architecture of your project

Comment: paste it into the question please, and format it. Code in comments is very difficult to read. In the "success" function, you write some javascript which will change the elements on the page. In your case, download some JSON data containing the values you want to put in the textboxes, and then write some script to insert them into the relevant boxes.

Comment: btw why are you using tables to lay out your form? Tables are for displaying data only, not for data entry. You can use CSS for this. Most people stopped using tables to format their web pages about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to achieve the dynamic loading of the data.An Example would be:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourscript.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

where yourscript.php is your backend script, where the database calls would be executed and returned back to your success on successful request.

Please note that the data should be exchanged in a serialized format(for AJAX requests the most common approach is JSON).

Comment: What is #results in line 5?

Comment: OP clearly has no/minimal knowledge of ajax. Don't confuse by giving an example which shows how to insert HTML into the page, and then say that the best way to do it is using JSON. If that's true, then give an example using JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by json.
Try the following code.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    include 'Connection.php';
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    $fetchquery = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from `registration` where `Emp_Code` = '$userid'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
    {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchquery))
        {
            $return['employeecode']=$row['Emp_Code'];
            $return['fullname']=$row['Full_Name'];
            $return['permanentaddress']=$row['Permanent_Address'];
            $return['mobileno']=$row['Mobile_No'];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$("#Fetchdetails").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : 'http://localhost/test/get_data.php?userid='+userId,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            $('#permanentaddress').val(response.permanentaddress);
            $('#employeecode').val(response.employeecode);
            $('#fullname').val(response.fullname);
            $('#mobileno').val(response.mobileno);
        },
        error : function() {
            alert('There was an error');
        }
    });
});
```

**Note** : you have to replace following line with your php file url.

url : 'http://localhost/test/get_data.php

Comment: you should use return, not die !

Comment: @t-n-y return would be appropriate if within a function, but it's not. Using return will probably be an error, or at best cause nothing to be sent to the browser. "echo" would be appropriate here. P.S. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection, it would be better to give an example using parameterised queries.

Comment: @ADyson my bad, he should put this code in a function then use return ;) or use echo

Comment: @Arpit_K Post what php return for this ajax call. You can check this in web developer console.

Comment: @ShaileshDaund : it shows  alert('There was an error');

Comment: @Arpit_K post your console output like this http://imgur.com/a/LxFhZ You can get console by pressing f12 on browser.

Comment: @ShaileshDaund it should be "echo" not "return". See earlier comments.